# Reassign loop variable inside for loop. Bug?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to understand why this code terminates (yes, I tested it) - https://github.com/drkyro/mmcFE-litecoin/blob/master/cronjobs/cronjob.php

```
34: for($i = 0; $i < $numAccounts; $i++){
.
.
.
63:             $i=0;
.
.
.
129: }
```

and this simple test never ends:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo "i1 = $i";
    $i=0;
}
```

What is the difference and why loop variable is not reassigned in first case?

Comment: Maybe `$numAccounts` is zero?

Comment: What is the rest of the code in your first example. You have at least two if statements that could prevent the `$i=0`. Are you sure the if statements get passed?

Comment: did you try `var_dump($numAccounts)` to see if the variable is set and is not equal to 0?

Comment: That's the problem: I just tried running on numAccounts = 5 and it did get inside those ifs 4 times. The value of $i at the end in those cases where 1,1,1,1. And then it stopped.

Answer (score 4):

Because `$i = 0` is not always executed. It is only executed if the account did not exist. The account is then created, so on the next pass `$i` is not reset to `0`. You need the context around the code as well.

A simplified view of just this behavior:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $numAccounts; $i++) {
    $accountExistsQ = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM networkBlocks WHERE accountAddress = '".$transactions[$i]["txid"]."' ORDER BY blockNumber DESC LIMIT 0,1")or die(mysql_error());
    $accountExists = mysql_num_rows($accountExistsQ);

    if(!$accountExists) {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `networkBlocks` (`blockNumber`, `timestamp`, `accountAddress`, `confirms`, `difficulty`) ".
        "VALUES ('$assoc_block', '$assoc_timestamp', '" .$transactions[$i]["txid"]. "', '" .$transactions[$i]["confirmations"]. "', '$difficulty')");

      $i=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And if it is executed, there is also possibility that it is incremented up to 5

Comment: What I don't understand - can this loop terminate if it does get inside those ifs? It should loop forever, no? The value of $numAccounts is 240 in real world usage.

Comment: No. Read the code. Don't you see how it only sets `$i` to 0 **if the account doesn't exist** then inserts a new account? Then the next time it loops, it **does not enter the `if` because the account now exists**.

Comment: Now i get it. Thank you!

Comment: Dumb me - I commented out all insert statement to not to modify database and check other parts of the code. The thing run forever and it puzzled me.